# Growth factor of symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite matrix, and LU decompose it. Then we get $A = LL^T$.

The growth factor of matrix A is as follows
$$ \rho \equiv \frac{\max _{i, j}\left|u_{i j}\right|}{\max _{i, j}\left|a_{i j}\right|} $$
A textbook said that $\rho = 1$, but I don't know how to prove it. 
Would anybody elaborate this?

Comment: Probably, $\rho \leq 1$